# CoreMotion iOS 5 attitude with reference frame doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-motion

i'm trying the new features of CoreMotion, above all the possibility to set the reference frame, but if i use a DeviceMotionHandler and the reference frame set to CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical the output is the some of CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical.
i start the app with the iphone always in the same yaw rotation respect my desk, and i test different initial yaw rotation, but the result is always the same.

```
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = YES;
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;    

CMDeviceMotionHandler  motionHandler = ^ (CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%f      %f         %f", motion.attitude.pitch, motion.attitude.roll, motion.attitude.yaw);
};

[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:motionHandler];
```

i found the solution of my problem, but i can't understand why the previous code doesn't work.
I add just a CMAttitude variable *a in motionHandler.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = YES;
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;    

CMDeviceMotionHandler  motionHandler = ^ (CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    CMAttitude *a = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude;
    labelAngle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f      %f         %f",a.pitch, a.roll,a.yaw];
    labelAngle2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f       %f      %f", motion.attitude.pitch, motion.attitude.roll, motion.attitude.yaw];
};

[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:motionHandler];}
```

Comment: I see the same behavior. The attitude in the motion parameter that is passed to the block seems to be the "normal" attitude, while the attitude in the deviceMotion property seems to be compensated with the reference frame. I wonder if this is a bug, or whether I can rely on this behaviour, as it is quite useful. Combining the two makes it possible to compensate for the quirky magnetic behaviour of iPhone with a stable gyro derived direction.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug towards Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/59/wo/1sukWbI5nvOZQ2Y6MPBXnw/14.66

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because .. if you define the handler first, the attitude property of your motion object has already been set to the default value. Later in your own code this attitude property becomes read only. So, when you start the motion updates with this handler the attitude property of motion no longer can be changed. But the attitude property of motionManager.deviceMotion is set to whatever you specify in startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame and this is being read into the a object when you start the motion updates with startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame. The a object now has the correct attitude, while the motion object has the default attitude.

Comment: i try to define the motionHandler inside the method startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame, but the the result it's always the same. 
`    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
        CMAttitude *test = motion.testAttitude;
        labelAncle4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f       %f      %f", radiansToDegree(test.pitch),radiansToDegree(test.roll), radiansToDegree(test.yaw)];
    }];
`

Comment: It is obvious that my former answer is not correct. It is also obvious that this two CMDeviceMotion instances are not the same. The reference frame obviously belongs to the CMDeviceMotionMananger.deviceMotion object and not to the CMDeviceMotion object specified in the handler. Is this maybe a bug?

Comment: A CMDeviceMotion object do not have any attitudeReferenceFrame itself. A attitudeReferenceFrame is a property of a CMMotionManager object. I really thought that the handlers pointer to the CMDeviceMotion object was a pointer to the CMMotionManagers property deviceMotion. It is obviously not, but rather a pointer to data before any referenceframe.